# Using Paper Trail to find the user who updated the current version of the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

The project I am working is using the Paper Trail gem to store previous versions of certain models.

I'm using this to display an audit history page on the models view page which shows what was changed between model updates and who changed it. This is working fine for the previous versions, but I would also like to show who updated the current version of the model.

Is there a version of the whodunnit command to find who updated the model to its current state?

I figured Paper Trail must store it somewhere for the current version otherwise it wouldn't know for when it populates the model.versions array on the next update.

I've searched on Stack Overflow and even started looking through the gems code, but I couldn't work out how it stores whodunnit for the current_version.

Answer (score 0):

//Returns true if this widget(object) is the current, live one; or false if it is from a previous version.

```
widget.live?
```

//Return the version this widget was reified from, or nil if it is live.
You can customise the name of the method.

```
widget.version
```

If object is live then version is nil

You can fetch the last version as

```
widget.versions.last.whodunnit

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def user_for_paper_trail
    user_signed_in? ? current_user : 'Guest'
  end

  def info_for_paper_trail
    { user_id: current_user.id } if user_signed_in?
  end
end

# config/initializers/paper_trail.rb
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
end
```